# Зачем функции CreateDIBSection - контекст устройства?

Tags: winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, зачем функции CreateDIBSection - первый параметр "дескриптор контекста устройства" ? То есть как она его использует ? Разве для выделения участка памяти и возвращения указателя на него - недостаточно информации во втором параметре в структуре BITMAPINFO, где как раз и описывается по сути какой буффер мне нужно выделить ?
Я не понимаю, как тут контекст устройства участвует.

Answer (score 1):

Для копирования цветов из палитры устройства (если они индексированные). Из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection):

> If the value of iUsage is DIB_PAL_COLORS, the function uses this device context's logical palette to initialize the DIB colors.